# Removal of page breaks; rows within a dataset with R

Tags: r

I have a series of non-standard files that I'd like to bring into R - previously I've simply used Excel to work with this data but I'd like to use R to automate my work a little.

There are a couple of 'header information' sheets that I can simply remove by using 'skip' in read.table. Throughout the files, there are page breaks after every 10 records. Also, each page reproduces the column headers etc. as well.

Also, the last 3 columns are offset by one row which I'll need to shift down at some point.

Any pointers you can share? [Here is a grab of a section of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svBRE.jpg)

Comment: Are you limited to only using R here?  This would be a very manageable thing using something like Java.

Comment: `?readLines` is a start, also add [reproducible example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) to your post.